# Executar Thread serializada

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Tenho a seguinte questão:

**1 -** Tenho uma rotina que percorre um banco de dados, que tem informações de arquivos que precisam sem escritos, poderá ter até 100 cadastros.

**2 -** A aplicação precisa percorrer registro a registro, e coletar as informações, e escrever os arquivos.

**3 -** O arquivos a serem escritos podem ser grande tamanho.

**4 -** Precisam ser escritos sequencialmente, ou seja a cada arquivo escrito, dai então a aplicação irá para o próximo.

Desenvolvi o código abaixo usando Thread.

**Problemas:**

**1 -** Da forma que está todos os JOBs, são executados ao mesmo tempo, coisa que conforme percebi, não poderá acontecer, pois se o banco de dados for muito grande, o consumo de memória por JOB, fica imenso.

Eu preciso que mesmo que esteja usando o conceito de paralelismo da Thread, esta rotina funcione serializada, ou seja, registro a registro, somente quando uma Thread terminar, a outra poderá começar.

Tentei utilziando WaitFor, mas como ele está no processo principal travou a aplicação, coisa que não pode acontecer.

Tentei várias possibilidades mas não consegui, alguém poderia dar uma dica de como fazer isso? 
Executar a Thread sequencialmente, porem com o paralelismo?

```
while not dm.quArquivos do 
begin 
nControleThreads := nControleThreads + 1; 
thEscreveArquivo:= tEscreveArquivo.Create(True); 
thEscreveArquivo.sDriverId := dm.quBancoTIPO_BANCO.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sDataBase := dm.quBancoDATABASE.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sOwner := dm.quBancoOWNER.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sServer := dm.quBancoSERVIDOR.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sipserver := dm.quBancoIP.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sPort := dm.quBancoPORTA.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sCharacterSet := 'utf8'; 
thEscreveArquivo.sUserName := dm.quBancoUSUARIO.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sPassWord := dm.quBancoSENHA.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sTodosDatabase := 
dm.quBancoTODOS_DATABASE.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sNomeArquivo := sNomeArquivoOrigem; 
thEscreveArquivo.sNomeArquivoZip := sNomeArquivoZipDestino; 
thEscreveArquivo.sSenhaCritpoGrafia := 
dm.quConfigsenha_criptografia.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sAlias := dm.quBancoALIAS.AsString; 
thEscreveArquivo.sCaminho := sCaminho; 
thEscreveArquivo.IidBanco := dm.quBancoID.AsInteger; 
thEscreveArquivo.FreeOnTerminate := True; 
thEscreveArquivo.OnTerminate := ControleThreads; 
thEscreveArquivo.Start; 

Sleep(2000); 
dm.quArquivos.Next; 
end;
```

Comment: Se um pode ser escrito APENAS quando o outro terminar, qual o sentido de utilizar thread?

Comment: O sentido seria apenas não travar a aplicação, visto que o processo é pesado e demorado.

Answer (score 1):

Se a intenção é apenas não travar a aplicação. Tente da seguinte forma:

```
var
  vTarefa: TThread;
begin
  vTarefa := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      ... // Faça todo procedimento aqui  
    end);

  vTarefa.Start;
  while vTarefa.Finished = False then
    Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Observe que criamos uma "tarefa" e deixamos a aplicação esperando ela terminar. Como existe um "ProcessMessages" a aplicação fica em idle esperando. Este processo é ruim, pois, eleva bastante o nível de processamento da aplicação.

O Ideal será você pausar o `while` por alguns milessegundos...
algo como:

```
while vTarefa.Finished = False then
begin
  Sleep(10) // Aqui você precisa medir quanto precisa, geralmente 10 é suficiente
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Se estiver no Xe10 é muito melhor utilizar as [Task](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_TTask_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library)

Comment: Bom dia Junior.
Obrigado pelo apoio, vou validar e retorno.